# Lauching by an element ID or by class group not working in intro.js

Tags: jquery, intro.js

I've made a simple test in intro.js example ... changing in the Chrome DevTools the button action

```
<a class="btn btn-large btn-success" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:introJs('.test').start();">Show me how</a>
```

and a step information , adding a class :

```
<div class="span6 test" data-step="2" data-intro="Ok, wasn't that fun?">
  <h4>Easy to Use</h4>
  ...
```

Any ideas what can it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's a little bit wrong, if you read the readme you can see that the `introJs` parameter is for the farm of the steps/elements. So your code should be something like:

```
<div class='test'>
    <div class="span6 test" data-step="2" data-intro="Ok, wasn't that fun?">
      <h4>Easy to Use</h4>
      ...
</div>
```

And now `introJs('.test').start();` should work correctly.

Comment: TY dude, although I guess it would be a nice ideia implement the other way too